# How to add UITableView just below NavigationBar using AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, ios6, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, ios7

Using NSLayoutConstraint I can add the table view but in Landscape there is a gap between those , as I am giving constant 64 to its top.Is there any way to assign Navigation Bar's height to it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a UIViewController or a UITableViewController?

Comment: UIViewController  and on top of it I am adding Table view

Comment: Are you setting up autolayout in interface builder?

Comment: No I am adding it programetically .

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .xib, in Attributes Inspector (4. tab) > Simulated Metrics > select Navigation Bar for Top Bar.

Comment: This doesn't help, the view sstill has a y position as if there was notnavigation bar (i.e. underneath it).

Answer (score 0):

Embed your view controller with an Navigation Controller.To do that select you view controller  and select editor -> embed in -> navigation controller

Comment: @SAURAV You can do it in your storyboard.

Comment: Its not working ...Please suggest how can I do it by fetching the navigation bar height and assign it to the tableview's origin.

Comment: @SAURAV In your app delegate under applicationDidFinishLaunching:

Comment: navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];
   MyViewController *firstController=[[MyViewController alloc] init];
   [navController pushViewController:firstController animated:NO];
   [window addSubview navController.view];